# Join on different tables depending on column data in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Is there a way for me to join a table to other tables depending on the data in the cell used in the joining?

I have commented out the code in the join loop to demonstrate how I would want to approach this issue.  Basically I want to be able to join one table to either three tables depending on the table name.  The column CK_PaymentTableName can only contain either of 3 strings: "PaymentCash", "PaymentBank" or "PaymentCard".

**Here is my pseudo code:**

```
select 
    st.ID,
    u.Name,
    st.Comment as Comment
from SalesTable st
    inner join Stuff1 s1 on s1.FK_SalesTableID = st.ID
    inner join Unit u on s1.FK_UnitID = u.UnitID
    --left outer join PaymentBank pba on case 
        --when s1.CK_PaymentTableName = 'PaymentBank' 
        --then pba.PaymentBankID else null end = pba.PaymentBankID
    --left outer join PaymentCard pcc on case 
        --when s1.CK_PaymentTableName = 'PaymentCard' 
        --then pcc.PaymentCardID else null end = pcc.PaymentCardID
    --left outer join PaymentCash pca on case 
        --when s1.CK_PaymentTableName = 'PaymentBank' 
        --then pca.PaymentCashID else null end = pca.PaymentCashID
where 
    st.Derp = 'derp'
group by 
    st.ID, 
    st.Comment, 
    u.Name
```

Comment: What are you actually joining on though? It looks like you have no link between Stuff1 and the payment tables.

Comment: Is dynamic sql an option? If so, based on the condition joins can be built.

Comment: you can use a case statements in a join

Comment: Sorry for my abbreviated code.  I was actually trying to use `case` statements but I could get them to work for my joining statements.  But no, my SalesTable does not have a PaymentId.  The only reference to a paymentType is within the Stuff1 table, it only has the 3 strings a stated above.

Comment: Does any of the payment tables have a sales id?  How do you expect to join the data correctly?

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.  I know this schema is very weird but this is the system that was dumped in my hands and I have to deal with.  Anyway, it seems I was close to the solution myself and @TMNT2014 came with the solution that works for me.  Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not Just do an "And" Instead of the CASE? Essentially you dont even need that. Since it is a left Join it will have results if the condition is true.

```
select 
    st.ID,
    u.Name,
    st.Comment as Comment
from SalesTable st
   inner join Stuff1 s1 on s1.FK_SalesTableID = st.ID
   inner join Unit u on s1.FK_UnitID = u.UnitID
   left outer join PaymentBank pba on s1.CK_PaymentTableName = 'PaymentBank' 
   left outer join PaymentCard pcc on s1.CK_PaymentTableName = 'PaymentCard' 
   left outer join PaymentCash pca on s1.CK_PaymentTableName = 'PaymentCash' 
where 
  st.Derp = 'derp'
group by 
  st.ID, 
  st.Comment, 
  u.Name
```

Comment: I guess I over complicate my thought process. @TMNT2014 thanks for reminding me that sometimes we need to start from bottom up. Thanks.